# getting the POST request from web server

Tags: php, soap, curl, centos

I'm having troubles debugging a POST request I'm making from my web server to another web server.
I'm trying to communicate with a SOAP web service but from some reason a code that worked well from local machine fails when executing on my server
Looking for a way to see the post request my server make to the web service server
web server OS - CentOs
using PHP curl to make the request
Ideas anyone?

Comment: So to understand the question, you want to record/capture the SOAP request on the server that makes or sends the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark? If you've got to connect to the remote end using SSL, then run a stunnel client on the soap client and route requests through that tapping in between.

Comment: can you detail?
I tried wireshark but I can't see my server traffic just my local

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and using CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT made outgoing request headers show up in debug info.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($data);
$details = curl_getinfo($ch);
var_dump($details);
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the POST on the server

$h=fopen('out.txt','w');
fwrite($h,var_export($_POST,true));

Maybe the curl is disabled on your server

Comment: thanks, but it is enabled (working with it on some other functionalities) as for the $_POST it only shooes the post to my server not the post my server makes to other servers

Answer (score 0):

Or point your client at:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

C.

Comment: this will give me the POST request to my server I need the POST i'm making to the other (not mine) server

Comment: Yse - but if you just the server and path in the URL it will still send the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect the post request to a server you control. You can then read the posted data using `echo file_get_contents('php://input');`